# Updating a layer's bounding box in GeoServer after WFS-T insert

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, wfs-t

I'm creating a data store in GeoServer from an OpenLayers DrawFeature control, using WFS-T to save the geometry into GeoServer. This works great, except the data store's bounding box doesn't get set in GeoServer. However, if you create a data store from a shapefile, the bounding box gets automatically set. I know you can go into the GeoServer admin page and tell it to calculate the bounding box, but I need a way to do it programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no easy way to do it (no REST api and no URL hacking thanks to Wicket [pun intended]).
In case you feel like coding, the source of the webui that handles the update of the bbox is in [BasicResourceConfig.java](http://svn.codehaus.org/geoserver/trunk/src/web/core/src/main/java/org/geoserver/web/data/resource/BasicResourceConfig.java).

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the BoundingBox manually in GeoServer. If you can predict the bounds of your inserted data, you can set it beforehand. You could use for example the bounds of your country or region you are working with.